# mysql multiple fields from subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT date FROM forums WHERE topic_id=f.id OR id=f.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) as last_reply, 
  f.*, p.id as pid, p.name FROM forums f 
      INNER JOIN players p ON p.id = f.author 
  WHERE f.topic_id=0 ORDER BY f.id DESC
```

In the subquery, I'd like to return not only the `date` field, but also the `author` field as well. how can I do this?

looked at a similar post but can't apply it to mine.

Comment: Did you try adding author to the list of things you select, like this: `(SELECT date, author FROM forums WHERE...)`

Comment: yes but the subquery is designed to search for the last posters id, not the topic poster id

Comment: I'd recommend you provide some info about the tables, because that query just doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it something like this:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT date FROM forums WHERE topic_id=f.id OR id=f.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) as last_reply,
  (SELECT author FROM forums WHERE topic_id=f.id OR id=f.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) as last_author,
  f.*, p.id as pid, p.name FROM forums f 
      INNER JOIN players p ON p.id = f.author 
  WHERE f.topic_id=0 ORDER BY f.id DESC
```

I would actually repeat the subquery again

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this can help you :

```
SELECT MAX(f.date), f.author
FROM forums f
    INNER JOIN players p ON
        p.id = f.author
WHERE f.tpoic_id = 0
GROUP BY f.author
ORDER BY f.id DESC
```

But it's difficult with no structure of tables.

Good luck.